# Tomcat: how to utilize large memory on a Windows server

Tags: tomcat

My Tomcat (8.0.23) runs on a dedicated web server (Windows Server Standard 2012 R2 and the machine is Dell RX930). In addition to serving web content, the web app talks to the backend database and Elasticsearch.

All the files of the web app are about 45M on disk. The server has **128GB** memory.

These are Tomcat start Java options:

```
-Dcatalina.home=E:\Tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.32
-Dcatalina.base=E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.32
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\conf\logging.properties

Initial memory pool: 128 MB
Maximum memory pool: 256 MB
```

These options are actually the default values after installation (via apache-tomcat-8.0.32.exe) and I hope to know the values good for my environment.

How can I use such large memory? I understand that I may not need so much memory.

Comment: Careful what you wish for: The more memory you allocate, the longer garbage collection will take. Long GC breaks are the last thing you want in a web application.

Comment: Olaf, thanks for your input! I understand this caveat. I simply would like to have some practical settings from experienced people, instead of using default values. Regards.

Comment: You should consider scaling your application vertically and horizontally before trying to use 128GB in one go.

Comment: Alastair, I have two physical boxes and each box has two virtual servers and each virtual server has 128GB memory.

Comment: It depends on the profile of the application - do you need to optimise for low latency? Do you have a large data model? Do you have a lot of short lived objects? etc etc. Most people run multiple JVMs with < 16GB heap. You should consider reading up on scaling design.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to increase the heap-size of tomcat

and for that add an entry in [TOMCAT_HOME]/bin/setenv.bat (since you are using Windows OS)

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=" -server -Xms4g -Xmx4g %CATALINA_OPTS%"
```

**NOTE:**

You can change the value for Xms and Xmx option

**32 bit JDK** : max-heap-size: 4 GB

**64 bit JDK** : max-heap-size: Theoretical maximum memory for x64 machines is 2^64 bit but again its depend on how much your operating systems allows.I read some where that Windows allowed maximum of 32GB for 64 bit JVM. [Reference](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory.html)

Comment: In a server environment, set the initial and max to the same value

Comment: Alastair, what specific values you recommend for my environment? Could you post your input as an answer? It would be fantastic if you could recommend the other values for my environment if you know some changes are needed.

Comment: @curious1 there is no specific recommendation. We only know how much memory your server has, not how much memory your application needs and what load it will be under. Figure out the minimum that it can work with under the load you expect and add a security margin on top.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack updated the answer, thank for the suggestion.